# How do I only print an objects in a list which have 3 to 5 integers and one letter

Tags: python, regex

I have the list

```
 ['Product', '98', '100K', 'fifa15-ps-100k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '99', '200K', 'fifa15-ps-200k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '197', '300K', 'fifa15-ps-300k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '198', '400K', 'fifa15-ps-400k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '100', '500K', 'fifa15-ps-500k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '199', '600K', 'fifa15-ps-600k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '200', '700K', 'fifa15-ps-700k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '201', '800K', 'fifa15-ps-800k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '202', '900K', 'fifa15-ps-900k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '122', '1000K', 'fifa15-ps-1000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '235', '1500K', 'fifa15-ps-1500k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '125', '2000K', 'fifa15-ps-2000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '208', '3000K', 'fifa15-ps-3000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '209', '4000K', 'fifa15-ps-4000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '126', '5000K', 'fifa15-ps-5000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '216', '7000K', 'fifa15-ps-7000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '215', '10000K', 'fifa15-ps-10000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product']
```

I just want to print object in the list with 3-5 integers and one letter. For example:

```
[100k, 200k, 300k]
```

I tried to use regex but got nowhere, I only know really simple regex. Just a pointer in the right direction would be helpfull

Comment: What about  `'12K34'`?

Comment: I don't know how is this unclear for you people...

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary here it is `[x for x in lst if re.match(r'(?m)^(?=(?:\D*\d){3,5}\D*$)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z]*$).*', x)]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj I voted because as you can see people are posting two sets of answer: One that assumed that the letter always follows the numbers ans some like my comment work based on count. So, that's why unclear. If you want me to re-open I can totally re-vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re` as other answers have stated - however, it looks like you have tabular data (a flat list of 17 rows with 6 columns each) and are trying to retrieve the 3rd column from each "row", so you can slice it, eg:

```
>>> data[2::6]
['100K', '200K', '300K', '400K', '500K', '600K', '700K', '800K', '900K', '1000K', '1500K', '2000K', '3000K', '4000K', '5000K', '7000K', '10000K']
```

If you really, really, really wanted to only take something that had only between 3 and 5 numbers and a single letter that occurred *in any sequence*, then you could classify each character, count those up, and do appropriate checks, eg:

```
from collections import Counter
from unicodedata import category

def matches(text):
    counts = Counter(category(ch)[0] for ch in text)
    return (
        3 <= counts['N'] <= 5 # between 3-5 numbers
        and counts['L'] == 1 # has a single letter
        and not {'N', 'L'}.difference(counts) # doesn't contain anything else
    )
```

Comment: this is probably the best solution if the question is interpreted literally the regexs will not work on "K300" etc..

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> p = '^[0-9]{3,5}[a-zA-Z]{1}'
>>> [i for i in l if re.match(p, i)]
['100K', '200K', '300K', '400K', '500K', '600K', '700K', '800K', '900K', '1000K', '1500K', '2000K', '3000K', '4000K', '5000K', '7000K', '10000K']
```

Comment: The regex could be better as `(?i)\d{3,5}[a-z]` and you might want to consider using `re.match` (so you don't have to anchor the match to the start) instead of `re.findall`

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm still a bit shaky with regexes as I don't use them often, I know them just well enough to hack things together. Out of curiosity, what is the `(?i)` in the beginning of the pattern?

Comment: You could also use `filter(p.match, l)`.

Comment: @Cyber the `(?i)` is the same as passing `flags=re.I` to the `re` object - it makes the expression case insensitive - although there's nothing wrong with using `[a-zA-Z]` (which probably makes more sense in this case)

Comment: @RushyPanchal you could, but a list-comp will produce the desired result in both 2.x and 3.x. In 3.x `filter` no longer returns a list so it has the potential to produce surprising results. Probably the best way of doing this is `matches = re.compile(r'\d{3,5}[a-zA-Z]').match` then `[el for el in the_list if matches(el)]` to save a few name looks up etc...

Comment: @JonClements ah okay, fair enough. I don't use 3.x so didn't know there was a difference. Thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

# bound function; same as
# wanted = lambda s: re.match("^\d{3,5}[a-z]$", s, re.I)
wanted = re.compile("^\d{3,5}[a-z]$", re.I).match

# breaking down the regex:
#   ^        starts at the beginning of the string
#            (redundant because .match does that anyway,
#             but I like to make it explicit)
#   \d{3,5}  3 to 5 digits
#   [a-z]    any letter (re.I makes it case insensitive,
#              so it will also match A-Z)
#   $        goes right to the end of the string

data = ['Product', '98', '100K', 'fifa15-ps-100k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '99', '200K', 'fifa15-ps-200k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '197', '300K', 'fifa15-ps-300k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '198', '400K', 'fifa15-ps-400k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '100', '500K', 'fifa15-ps-500k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '199', '600K', 'fifa15-ps-600k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '200', '700K', 'fifa15-ps-700k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '201', '800K', 'fifa15-ps-800k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '202', '900K', 'fifa15-ps-900k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '122', '1000K', 'fifa15-ps-1000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '235', '1500K', 'fifa15-ps-1500k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '125', '2000K', 'fifa15-ps-2000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '208', '3000K', 'fifa15-ps-3000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '209', '4000K', 'fifa15-ps-4000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '126', '5000K', 'fifa15-ps-5000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '216', '7000K', 'fifa15-ps-7000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product', '215', '10000K', 'fifa15-ps-10000k', 'K', 'gold', 'Product']
res = [d for d in data if wanted(d)]

print(res)
```

gives

```
['100K', '200K', '300K', '400K', '500K', '600K', '700K', '800K', '900K', '1000K', '1500K', '2000K', '3000K', '4000K', '5000K', '7000K', '10000K']
```

Answer (score 1):

without using re and if `'98K3'` and  `'K100'` are possibilities:

```
from string import ascii_letters,digits
print [ele for ele in l if 3 <= len(ele) - len(ele.translate(None,digits)) <= 5 and len(ele) - len(ele.lower().translate(None, ascii_letters)) ==1 ]

['100K', '200K', '300K', '400K', '500K', '600K', '700K', '800K', '900K', '1000K', '1500K', '2000K', '3000K', '4000K', '5000K', '7000K', '10000K']
```

Comment: You might be interested in my updated answer where I've also done this, but in a different way. No doubt this'll be faster (`.translate` *is fast*) but  sadly differs between usage in 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @JonClements, I was actually going to use a Counter solution but got lazy.  looks pretty neat but you already have my +1 ;)